# r counting the combination of time

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, aggregate, reshape

This is harder to code, even harder to explain. My apologies if my explanation is confusing, I will try to explain the data this way.

I have a dataset with 3 columns

```
ID        Vaccine        Time
 1         A              Winter
 1         B              Spring
 
 2         A              Spring
 2         B              Winter
 2         B              Fall
 
 3         C              Fall
 3         A              Fall
 3         B              Fall

 4         A              Winter
 4         A              Spring

 5         A              Winter
```

As you can see there are

- 5 patients here and
- each can take, any or all, of the 3 vaccines A,B,C.
- There are 3 seasons: Winter, Spring, Fall.
- Vaccine A

  - A total of 5 patients took Vaccine A
  - 4 patients (patient 1, patient 2, patient 3, patient 5) took the vaccine only once

    Winter

    - Patient 1
    - Patient 5

    Spring

    - Patient 2

    Fall

    - Patient 3
  - 1 patient (patient 4) took the vaccine twice during Winter and spring

---

```
Vaccine      Winter.Only     Spring.Only       Fall.Only     Winter.Spring     Winter.Fall    Spring.Fall
A            2               1                 1             1
```

- Vaccine B

  - A total of 3 patients took Vaccine B
  - 2 patients took the vaccine only once (patient 1, patient 3)

    Spring

    - Patient 1

    Fall

    - Patient 3
  - 1 patient (patient 2) took the vaccine twice during Winter and Fall

---

```
Vaccine      Winter.Only     Spring.Only       Fall.Only     Winter.Spring     Winter.Fall    Spring.Fall
B                            1                 1                               1
```

- Vaccine C

  - A total of 1 patient took Vaccine C
  - 1 patient took the vaccine only once (patient 3)

    Fall

    - Patient 3

---

```
Vaccine      Winter.Only     Spring.Only       Fall.Only     Winter.Spring     Winter.Fall    Spring.Fall
C                                              1
```

The final dataset should look like this

```
Vaccine      Winter.Only     Spring.Only       Fall.Only     Winter.Spring     Winter.Fall    Spring.Fall
A            2               1                 1             1 
B                            1                 1                               1 
C                                              1
```

Mainly I am trying to create a dataset for each vaccine (row), how many patients took only one vaccine and when (Winter, Spring, Fall) and how many patients took two or three vaccines of the same type and when (Winter.Spring or Winter.Fall or  Spring. Fall or Winter.Spring.Fall)

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(Time) %>%
  group_by(ID, Vaccine) %>%
  summarize(Times = paste(Time, collapse = "_and_"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  count(Vaccine, Times) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Times, values_from = n)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Vaccine  Fall Spring Spring_and_Winter Winter Fall_and_Winter
  <chr>   <int>  <int>             <int>  <int>           <int>
1 A           1      1                 1      2              NA
2 B           1      1                NA     NA               1
3 C           1     NA                NA     NA              NA
```